# Regex for numbers, hyphen and plus +

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I'm using the jquery validation engine and trying to add a custom validation with regexp.

But how to set it to only allow numbers, hyphens and + sign?

I tried it in different ways like:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z -+]+$
^[0-9a-zA-Z -\+]+$
```

But none of them worked if I put the plus sign after the hyphen. Why?

Answer (score 3):

In a character class, the `-` (hyphen) is used to indicate character ranges (just like `0-9` means from `0` to `9`). You can either escape it, or put it at the end to make it work properly:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\-+]+$

^[0-9a-zA-Z+-]+$
```

EDIT: Also, I'm not sure what you put the space in there. I removed it due to your restriction, but you can add it back (before the hyphen for the second regex) if need be.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen creates a range (just like you did with `0-9`. In your case it generates a range from space to `+` (in ASCII/Unicode order). That's quite a bunch of characters: `!"#$%&'()*+` and the space itself.

Escape the hyphen or put it at the end (and remove the space unless you want to accept spaces):

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z+-]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

`-` has special meaning in a character class. In fact, you're even using it to that end in your `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` groups.

To use a literal hyphen, either escape it `\-` or just put it at the end of the class (right before the `]`)

Answer (score 0):

try this regex pattern

```
 ^[0-9a-zA-Z+-]+$
```

Comment: a) This will match any string. As in, there is no string that could make this pattern fail b) The case-insensitive flag is redundant (or `A-Z` is). c) There are two spaces in the pattern (and I think the OP doesn't even want the space in there). d) The character class contains a range from space to underscore which includes [almost every other printable ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com/) e) (Please include an explanation with your pattern)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177757/are-answers-that-just-contain-a-regular-expression-pattern-really-good-answers)

Comment: ok thanks @m.buettner to explain me the procedure

Comment: i edited my code i see my previous answer and check and you are right now i implement now pattern